# How to create interactive shape at flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create an application in a flutter that shows the map as in the picture, Where the user can enlarge the image and when he clicks on the figure, more details appear Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To zoom in & out and drag a picture you can use `InteractiveViewer` widget or `extended_image` package. You can also use `MouseRegion` widget to detect position on click/touch but I don't know how you can use it on a picture.
I think you can also use `graphview` package to draw your picture like a map instead, and I think it might help with the "onClick" part(I'm not sure though).

Comment: If you need an example for `graphview` use can download the app `flutter catalog` on [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.x_wei.flutter_catalog) or [appstore](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1602928862) and look for `graphview`.

Comment: Thank you ,very useful answer,now the problem is how to click on shape in graphview?

Comment: If you tried the example in the app, I think you can wrap `Chip` with `GestureDetector`(it may be better to set `behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque`) and use `onTap` to do your click operations.

Comment: thank you again , i will try to follow all your instructions 
i have a last question how i can  change the name of the node?
for example node1 to first step node2 to second step...

Comment: I don't know how you wrote your code but I suggest to create a `List<String>` of your node' texts and use them like `Text('$list[index]')`.

Comment: i want to edit the names of nodes in  [the app](https://x-wei.github.io/flutter_catalog/#/)  ,part of -Charts-Graphview- can you help me?